# Dividir columna en valores repetidos y únicos

Tags: r

Parto de estos datos

```
datos <- read.table(text = '
Id  col1    
1   aaaa        
2   aaaa        
3   bbb     
4   aaaa        
5   34c4fcc         
6   3ef3        
7   2ee     
8   34c4fcc         
9   5       
10  4       
11  5       
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Quiero poner los elementos repetidos en una columna y los valores únicos en otra

```
Id  col1         repetidos    unicos
1   aaaa          aaaa   
2   aaaa          aaaa   
3   bbb                        bbb
4   aaaa          aaaa   
5   34c4fcc       34c4fcc    
6   3ef3                       3ef3
7   2ee                        2ee
8   34c4fcc       34c4fcc    
9   5             5  
10  4                          4
11  5             5
```

He hecho un `summarise(count = n())` con un `group_by` para contar las veces que aparece cada elemento. Luego he intentado un if n>1 va a una columna y en caso contrario a otra, pero es una idea equivocada, creo que hay q sacar una lista de elementos para que al crear la columna vaya a la posición de la columna que le corresponde.

Aunque seguro que hay alguna función o librería que lo hace de golpe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un flujo alternativo completamente desarrollado con dplyr. La clave aquí está en que después del `group_by` no haces un `summarise`, sino que en el `mutate` añades el conteo `n()` a cada fila. De esta manera mantienes el dataset inicial y añades el conteo a cada grupo directamente:

```r
datos <- read.table(text = "
Id  col1    
1   aaaa        
2   aaaa        
3   bbb     
4   aaaa        
5   34c4fcc         
6   3ef3        
7   2ee     
8   34c4fcc         
9   5       
10  4       
11  5       
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

datos_dup <- datos %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  mutate(
    n = n(),
    repetidos = ifelse(n > 1, col1, NA),
    unicos = ifelse(n == 1, col1, NA)
  ) %>%
  select(-n)

datos_dup
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#> # Groups:   col1 [7]
#>       Id col1    repetidos unicos
#>    <int> <chr>   <chr>     <chr> 
#>  1     1 aaaa    aaaa      <NA>  
#>  2     2 aaaa    aaaa      <NA>  
#>  3     3 bbb     <NA>      bbb   
#>  4     4 aaaa    aaaa      <NA>  
#>  5     5 34c4fcc 34c4fcc   <NA>  
#>  6     6 3ef3    <NA>      3ef3  
#>  7     7 2ee     <NA>      2ee   
#>  8     8 34c4fcc 34c4fcc   <NA>  
#>  9     9 5       5         <NA>  
#> 10    10 4       <NA>      4     
#> 11    11 5       5         <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido sacar esto, por si a alguien le interesa. Seguro que muy mejorable.

**#Datos que se repiten.**

```
library(tidyverse)

datos %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  summarise(repe = n()) -> conteo

conteo[conteo$repe>1,]-> repetidos
conteo[conteo$repe==1,]-> no_repetidos
```

**#Busco las posiciones de los datos repetidos y no repetidos.**

```
which(datos$col1 %in% repetidos$col1)-> posiciones_repe
which(datos$col1 %in% no_repetidos$col1)-> posiciones_norepe
```

**#Añado las columnas de repetidos y únicos, y los datos según su posición.**

```
datos$repetidos <- NA
datos$unicos <- NA


datos[posiciones_repe,"repetidos"] <- datos[posiciones_repe, "col1"]
datos[posiciones_norepe,"unicos"] <- datos[posiciones_norepe, "col1"]
```

**Datos.**

```
   Id    col1 repetidos unicos
   1    aaaa      aaaa   <NA>
   2    aaaa      aaaa   <NA>
   3     bbb      <NA>    bbb
   4    aaaa      aaaa   <NA>
   5 34c4fcc   34c4fcc   <NA>
   6    3ef3      <NA>   3ef3
   7     2ee      <NA>    2ee
   8 34c4fcc   34c4fcc   <NA>
   9       5         5   <NA>
 10       4      <NA>      4
 11       5         5   <NA>
```